# jsPlumb: fat arrow?

Tags: javascript, jsplumb

I want a fat arrow in [jsPlumb](https://jsplumbtoolkit.com) with a pretty tip.

This is what I want:
[image]

This is what I get:
[image]

How can I change the settings?

Here's what I currently use:

```
PaintStyle: { stroke: "#f00", strokeWidth: 20 },
connector: ["Straight"],
connectorOverlays:[["Arrow", { location:1, width:70, length:70 } ]]
```

I have been using arrows in SVG before. There, I could simply change the SVG code of the head to be moved forward so that the end of the line (the coordinates of the line end point) is inside the arrowhead triangle. I don't seem to be able to do this in jsPlumb.

I see it is difficult to convey the problem.

Here's a next try:
[image]

Comment: did you try negative location? Not familiar with that library but arrow point and line start at same place and since arrow point is narrower you see the line

Comment: Good point - that's what I had originally expected. But anything <0 or >1 is taken as a number of pixels from start or end, respectively... See [docs](https://jsplumbtoolkit.com/community/doc/overlays.html#location). So you can't move "beyond" the line.

Comment: Aren't you able to change `connector` location? You cloud set it to start at 5 or so.

Comment: Thanks @FranciscoRodríguez: Any value outside the 0..1 range is interpreted as number of pixels _within_ the straight line (negative: from start, positive: from end). But what I would need is a way to push the arrow head _outside_ the line's endpoint (or alternatively, make the line shorter). I don't see any possibility for either.

Comment: What I was thinking is keep as it is the arrow and move the straight line. The pointer would be at the tip of the arrow, so it doesn't matter where to move the line (as I understand it)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting the location to 0.99 actually did the thing for me. Try this:

```
PaintStyle: { stroke: "#f00", strokeWidth: 20 },
connector: ["Straight"],
connectorOverlays:[["Arrow", { location:0.99, width:70, length:70 } ]]
```

Comment: Thank you @VaxoBasilidze. I'm afraid this makes no difference - please explain why you think this makes a difference.

Comment: @SwissMister I have edited my answer. Strange, but location: 0.99 actually does for me what you are trying to achieve. Try it also.

Comment: Thanks @VaxoBasilidze! That is one creative discovery! That works indeed. Actually, just changing `location` from `1` to `0.99` in my original code is the right answer in the current version of jsPlumb (2.5.7). If you edit your answer, I will accept it.

Answer (score 1):

This could probably work. Please try it out

```
connector: ["StateMachine", {curviness:0.001}],
connectorOverlays:[
  [
    "Arrow", 
    { location: [0.5, 0.5], width: 70, length: 70 } 
  ]
]
```

Check out the Overlay location section in this webpage https://jsplumbtoolkit.com/community/doc/overlays.html#adding

Comment: Thanks @NanduKalidindi. No luck. Tried this before - will indeed position the arrowhead in a better way - but it doesn't point in the direction of the arrow. See https://imgur.com/a/5CHG0

Comment: Surprising that it did not work, could you please create a JSFiddle if possible?

Comment: Is your connector type fixed or could it be changed. If yes then, please try changing it to `connector:"StateMachine"`

Comment: Very hot hint! You are right - this works. Alas, I need a "Straight" connector. Any way this could be fixed?

Comment: Just discovered I could set a small (albeit not zero!) `curviness` parameter to get an _almost_ straight arrow: `connector: ["StateMachine", {curviness:0.001}]`

Comment: @SwissMister Yep, the curviness indeed worked! I updated the answer.

Comment: @SwissMister Mark this as answer please, if it worked!

Answer (score 0):

This has no solution till date I guess by looking at github, It's still an [**open issue**](https://github.com/jsplumb/jsplumb/issues/252). Issue was opened in **2014**.

One solution would be hacking library itself to add margin or padding kind of property to Arrow Object.

### update:

I tried to figure out in library itself. See this below image where it's doing some math calculations. If you're good at it, tweak it and you're done!

[image: Extent calculations]

And `extents` are being user here:

[image: Extent usage]

### Update2:

Try Location array like below: (demo: http://jsfiddle.net/crerhawn/)

```
["Arrow", { location:[0.5,0.5], width:70, length:70 } ]
```